# How to include elements types in class model

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need a resulting `XML` like this:

```
<ListOfStudents>
    <ClassOfStudents value="1">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        ...
    </ClassOfStudents>
    <ClassOfStudents value="2">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        ...
    </ClassOfStudents>
    <ClassOfStudents value="3">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        ...
    </ClassOfStudents>
    <ClassOfStudents value="4">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        ...
    </ClassOfStudents>
    <ClassOfStudents value="5">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        <Student first="asf" last="asf">
        ...
    </ClassOfStudents>
</ListOfStudents>
```

Till now I have come up with this. But the problem is I can’t figure out how to include types in it?

```
public class ListOfStudents
{
    public ClassOfStudents _ClassOfStudents;
}

public class ClassOfStudents    
{
    public string Student;  
}
```

The value of types `value`, `first`, `last` would be assigned at the run-time but how should I model my classes to achieve the above XML after serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the `Student` have two properties maybe as string for `first` and `last`, the `ClassOfStudents` should hold a list of `Studnet`s and an id, and a `ListOfStudents` shoudl have a list of `ClassOfStudents`, that's all!

```
public class ListOfStudents
{
    public List<ClassOfStudents> ClassOfStudents;
}

public class ClassOfStudents    
{
    public int value;  
    public List<Student> Students;  
}

public class Student
{
    public string first;  
    public string last; 
}
```

And to deserialize into `ListOfStudents` see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document).

Answer (score 0):

I create model classes for achieving your xml .
I give you smiple way of create class file as per xml .
1. Create class file .
2.Copy xml content .
3. paste into class file as below snap .

You will get following result class file .

[image]

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class ListOfStudents
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ClassOfStudents")]
    public ListOfStudentsClassOfStudents[] ClassOfStudents { get; set; }
}


/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class ListOfStudentsClassOfStudents
{
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Student")]
    public ListOfStudentsClassOfStudentsStudent[] Student { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte value { get; set; }

}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class ListOfStudentsClassOfStudentsStudent
{
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string first { get; set; }
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string last { get; set; }

}
```

It will work as per your xml .

Thanks .